# How to Display Different Images in a Single Row using Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tr dir-paginate="NL in NewLaunchesData | filter:searchProducts|itemsPerPage:ItemsperPage track by $index">

        <td class="label-center">
            <a href="../fileUpload/MonthlyOffersImages/{{NL.FileName}}" download>
                <img src="../fileUpload/MonthlyOffersImages/{{NL.FileName}}" height="30px" width="30px"></img>
            </a>
            <br />
            {{NL.Subject}}
        </td>
        <td class="label-center">
            <a href="../fileUpload/MonthlyOffersImages/{{NL.FileName}}" download>
                <img src="../fileUpload/MonthlyOffersImages/{{NL.FileName}}" height="30px" width="30px"></img>
            </a>
            <br />
            {{NL.Subject}}
        </td>
        <td class="label-center">
            <a href="../fileUpload/MonthlyOffersImages/{{NL.FileName}}" download>
                <img src="../fileUpload/MonthlyOffersImages/{{NL.FileName}}" height="30px" width="30px"></img>
            </a>
            <br />
            {{NL.Subject}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I need to display in a row with three images, data should contain multiple rows.
I know repeater control in Asp.net, but I need to display multiple rows with images.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Chunk your image array into an array of arrays each containing 3 elements. Then simply iterate through the root array and then through the child arrays.

Comment: what is the issue with your current code ??

Comment: @Keshav This will simply display the same image three times.

Comment: Yes,Same Image Showing 3 Times,I need to Display 3 different images in a single row...Like a Repeater in asp.net

Comment: Hi, Can you use some CSS in your code? I suggest you to use something like grid system of Bootstrap. In that, u can make multiple columns of col-md-4 (which will divide the area into 3 equal parts) and apply ng-repeat on that. You can do this without bootstrap as well, just by using same kind of CSS.

Comment: @Spidi's Web  ..Yes it's working

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="row" ng-controller="NewOffersCtrl2">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="NL in NewLaunchesData">
                    <a href="../fileUpload/MonthlyOffersImages/{{NL.FileName}}" download><img src="../fileUpload/MonthlyOffersImages/{{NL.FileName}}" height="200px" width="200px"></img></a>
                    <br />
                    {{NL.Subject}}
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </div>
            </div>
  </div>
```